# My insert doesn't work but I don't get any errors

Tags: php, mysqli

My mysqli insert doesn't work for some reason but I don't get any errors.

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "dice");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `gamble` (thr,score,tstamp)
    VALUES ('test123','test123','test123')");
echo "New record has id: " . mysqli_insert_id($con);

mysqli_close($con);
```

I really don't know what I did wrong.

Comment: The script doesn't test for errors automatically, and you don't test for errors either (at least not when executing the insert statement). Check the result of `mysqli_query` and call `mysqli_error` to get more detailed error information.

Comment: `tstamp` sounds to be something like a timestamp. Writing a string to it most likely will break the stuff. What are the datatypes of the columns in `kgp`?

Comment: suggestion for improving the error handling: `mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO gamble (thr,score,tstamp)
VALUES ('test123','test123','test123')") or die (mysqli_error($con));`